# Agency for a maj recording artist wants to license logo for merch/marketing campaign. How to negotiate 1 time payment for use on co branded products?

Tags: logo, copyright, licensing

Agency for a major recording artist wants to license family business logo for merchandise/marketing campaign.

They are in the list of top selling recording artists in music history.

How to negotiate offered one time payment for logo use on co branded products & merchandise?

I have no idea how negotiate something like this.

It would have benefits to our business by free international advertising as well, but not sure what a fair one time fee / number would be to expect.

I don't want to name them because not sure if I can mention, but need good advice of appropriate fee to expect & associated advice.

Comment: Did you design the logo, or are you the “family business owner” (or both)?

Comment: Actually both. I designed it when a few years after we started the business.

Answer (score 1):

I'd speak to a professional, established, licensing agent, not a bunch of designers on the web.

Even if an agent requires a fee, it may be well worth it. A simple web search can find licensing agents.

There are most likely a bunch of small things you'll *never* think of that an established agent will be *well* aware of and have the knowledge to negotiate more appropriately.

Just like your clients don't *really* understand what goes into the creation for a logo, you will *never* really understand what needs to be covered, in writing, for a particular licensing agreement. It's more legalese than anything and while, certainly well-meaning, designers may offer advise... well.. clients *could * create their own logos. There's a reason they hire you, isn't there?